# How to avoid the glitch in Gerimund's Hall in Forbidden Legend quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I could not retrieve Galdur's Amulet in Gerimund's Hall when I first killed the brother (Sidgis?) because it seemed to be stuck underwater with no option to retrieve it.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as what causes the glitch in the first place, I am not sure if playing through Gerimund's Hall BEFORE you start the Forbidden Legend Quest, causes the amulet to get stuck under water with no option to retrieve it, BUT I found how to avoid it. It's all about where he lands after he is defeated.

I did have to play through it a second time when I reloaded the game from before I fought him, and happened to defeat Sidgis on land, near his coffin, so that he did not fall in the water, and was able to retrieve the amulet off of him and further the quest.

So I would save it right BEFORE you fight him, in case he lands in the water, and it glitches, so that you can load it again from immediately before the fight. Be aware, you will have to defeat him again at Reachwater Rock, when you go there to re-forge the amulet.

Comment: You can always post an answer if you have solutions, you don't need to leave a comment to other posts to do that. And please, refrain from begging for reputation, you should deserve it :)